# insert a variable in SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I have this code :

```
$params = $_GET["params"];
print $params;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
--->//$result = R::getAll( 'SELECT $params FROM user');
} elseif  ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

}
echo json_encode($result);
```

How correctly set a `$params` variable into my response. I make a request through `RedBeanPhP`

Comment: Injecting variables directly into the query is a ***very bad idea***. Read about SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use double quotes in order to have the variable value resolved.

instead of:

```
$result = R::getAll( 'SELECT $params FROM user');
```

Try:

```
$result = R::getAll("SELECT $params FROM user");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the params are in a format `id,username,email` you can just append new ones like so:

```
$params .= ',telephone';
```

**Keep in mind: this is a very unsecure way of connecting to your database, read about [SQL Incjection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)**

Answer (score 0):

You can read a bit about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

What you need to do is send a get-request with the variables you're after. It could look like this:

```
<form action="#" method="get">
  Some variable
  <input type="text" name="params" value="Foobar"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php
$params = $_GET["params"];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($params);
echo '</pre>';

/* This is redundant, considering your question
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
--->//$result = R::getAll( 'SELECT $params FROM user');
} elseif  ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {

}
echo json_encode($result);
*/
?>
```

### Explanation

**The HTML**

This part of the code is a form, where you set the method to be a get-request. The action-destination is `#`, which means that you're send it to the same page that it was sent from. And you define the variable `$_GET['params']` to be equal to `Foobar`. And it is submitted, when you press the submit-button.

```
<form action="#" method="get">
  Some variable
  <input type="text" name="params" value="Foobar"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**The PHP**

```
<?php
$params = $_GET["params"]; // This sets the `params`-get-variable.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($params); // This prints it, so it looks pretty. :-)
echo '</pre>';
?>
```